# Error using Vlookup and Table as range for data pull macro

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:

Dim PartNumber As String
Dim det As String

PartNumber = PartNumberIN.Text ' take part input from textbox

det = "Part Number: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PartNumber, Application.WorksheetFunction.Offset(Table1, 0, 2), 3, False)
det = det & vbNewLine & "Part Description: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PartNumber, Application.WorksheetFunction.Offset(Table1, 0, 4), 5, False)
det = det & vbNewLine & "CV or VA: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PartNumber, Application.WorksheetFunction.Offset(Table1, 0, 1), 2, False)
det = det & vbNewLine & "Direct Ship?: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PartNumber, Application.WorksheetFunction.Offset(Table1, 0, 3), 4, False)
det = det & vbNewLine & "Storage Container: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PartNumber, Application.WorksheetFunction.Offset(Table1, 0, 6), 7, False)
det = det & vbNewLine & "SAP Location: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PartNumber, Application.WorksheetFunction.Offset(Table1, 0, 13), 14, False)
det = det & vbNewLine & "Physical Location: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PartNumber, Application.WorksheetFunction.Offset(Table1, 0, 14), 15, False)
MsgBox "Part Details : " & vbNewLine & det
Exit Sub



MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Part not present in table."
ElseIf Err.Number = 13 Then
    MsgBox "You have entered an invalid value"
ElseIf Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "You're toast"
End If
```

The message box should display:
Part Number: (DATA PULLED)
CV or VA: ""
Direct Ship: ""

and so forth.

The data is pulled from a table on a separate sheet than the macro button.
The button simply opens the userform.

Looking for help. The reason the table is used as a range is that this data will be updated regularly, and a named dynamic range does not work.

Comment: Where is `Table1` defined?

Answer (score 0):

A bit simplified: I'm not following your use of Offset here, so you may need to adjust some of the column numbers...

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

    Dim PartNumber As String
    Dim det As String, m, rng

    'get the table's data range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("table1").DataBodyRange
    'Debug.Print rng.Address
    PartNumber = PartNumberIN.Text ' take part input from textbox

    'locate the row if there's a match in the first column
    m = Application.Match(PartNumber, rng.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        'got a match, so construct the message
        With rng.Rows(m)
            det = "Part Number: " & PartNumber 
            det = det & vbNewLine & .Cells(5).Value
            'etc...
            MsgBox "Part Details : " & vbNewLine & det
        End With
    Else
        'no match
        MsgBox "Part not present in table."
    End If

End Sub
```